# How do I unit-test HTTPS requests in Flask?

Tags: python, https, flask

For certain pages in a Flask app I'm creating, I have an HTTPS redirection system as follows.

```
def requires_https(f, code=302):
    """defaults to temp. redirect (301 is permanent)"""
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        passthrough_conditions = [
            request.is_secure,
            request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Proto', 'http') == 'https',
            'localhost' in request.url
        ]

        if not any(passthrough_conditions):
            if request.url.startswith('http://'):
                url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://')
                r = redirect(url, code=code)
                return r
    return decorated
```

If you're not requesting the HTTPS version of the page, it redirects you to it. I want to write unit tests for this service. I have written one that makes sure that you're redirected to the HTTPS version (check for a 301 or a 301, basically). I want to test that if you are requesting the https version of the page and are already on https, it does not redirect you (basically, for a 200). How do I get Flask to send an https request in the unit test?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @nu_everest This was a long, long time ago, and I didn't try Belrog's answer because the project was already over. IIRC we ended up getting an HTTPS certificate for the testing environment and writing a quick manual test...not ideal.

Answer (score 6):

You can force the Flask test's get() call to use HTTPS like this:

```py
response = self.app.get('/login', base_url='https://localhost')
assert(response.status_code == 200)
```

The addition of the base_url is used by the underlying Werkzeug to set the url scheme (HTTP/HTTPS). For local test calls like these the host name is not used, and can be left out. [You can see basic in code documentation for base_url here.](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/test.py#L244)

Comment: While this works, answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63708394/9415337 is much better. It allows less repetition (between different unit tests) and there's no need to hardcode the host address.

Answer (score 2):

There's a even easier Flask way to do that, just use the `PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME` configuration parameter equals to 'https'.

You can find it's definition [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/a1fb8f143f5deb545a10ac2758cb7a2b2bd68df3/src/flask/app.py#L303). You can find the rules how it's used internally by Flask [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/a1fb8f143f5deb545a10ac2758cb7a2b2bd68df3/src/flask/app.py#L1957). You can also find how its used [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/a1fb8f143f5deb545a10ac2758cb7a2b2bd68df3/src/flask/app.py#L1744).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work while @Belrog's answer does.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [unit testing for flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/)?

After your setup code, you'll have something like this

```
response = self.client.get(url)
self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 301)
self.assertEquals(resonse.text.find('https'), 0)
```

#### Update

It seems the best way forward is to create a werkzeug environment. Flask uses the werkzeug test client. You can have a look at the api [here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/test/). The quickstart (which is useful) is [over here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/test/).

You'll see that werkzeug has an EnvironBuilder with a base_url. Perhaps its possible to play around with that to mimic an https environment in your test suite.

Comment: This isn't really what I was looking for; I clarified it just now. I want to simulate an https request in a unit test.

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm really not sure if test suites cater for https testing. The above is my best shot at finding a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the python requests library: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Quite easy to do http requests with it.

Comment: I tried this, but I want the unit tests to run without me running an HTTPS server.

Answer (score -2):

With the requests library, you can ignore SSL with the verify flag.

```
requests.get('https://example.com', verify=False)
```

This will ignore SSL warnings from using a self-signed certificate

Comment: I tried this, but the issue is that I need to have an HTTPS server running (on port 483 or something). Does Flask provide facilities for this?