# How to test HTTPS in Flask

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, https

The following simplified code is defined in my flask app.

```
def select_url_for():
    if request.is_secure:
        return 's3'        
    return 'local'
```

I tried testing like this, and it works for HTTP.

```
def test_select_url_for(self):
    with self.app.test_request_context(): 
        self.assertTrue(select_url_for() == 'local')
```

How do I perform a similar test for the HTTPS with Flask?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094110/how-do-i-unit-test-https-requests-in-flask), but the question is unanswered. I need to run Flask in a HTTPS test mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.is_secure` check `wsgi.url_scheme` environment variable. By overriding it with `https` make `request.is_secure` returns `True`:

```
def test_select_url_for(self):
    with self.app.test_request_context(environ_overrides={
            'wsgi.url_scheme': 'https'
    }):
        self.assertEqual(select_url_for(), 'local')
```

BTW, instead of `assertTrue(a == b)`, use `assertEqual(a, b)` which give you more readable assertion failure message.